# VB.net Launcher Application Error

Tags: vb.net, launcher

i've been created launcher application with vb.net, but when the target application began, there was an error "Can not Read Start.ini file".
I tried with this code

```
Dim psi As New ProcessStartInfo()
With psi
     .FileName = sb.ToString
     .UseShellExecute = True
End With
Process.Start(psi)
```

how to fix it ?

Comment: maybe it needs its own proper working directory?

Answer (score 0):

Daniel probably has it right.  Try setting the `WorkingDirectory` property based off your FileName:

```
    Dim psi As New ProcessStartInfo()
    With psi
        .FileName = sb.ToString
        .WorkingDirectory = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(.FileName)
        .UseShellExecute = True
    End With
    Process.Start(psi)
```